# Sony xperia Z running Lollipop wont sync my contacts from google

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, contacts, sync, sony-xperia

My sony xperia Z wont sync all my contacts from google. I've tried re-setting the filter. Syncing contacts worked perfectly before upgrade. Now I've lost lots of contacts on my phone and it wont correct when I sync to online google where I can see the contacts exist. What should I try?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem too. My workaround was to create a new contact and save it to my Google account. Then it all suddenly showed up.